# How can I convert this random.choices python list to a string?

Tags: python, string, list, discord

I am making a Discord bot using Python,
I want the bot to react with a random message, which works fine using `random.choice`
However, I wanted to add something. I found that with `random.choices` (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices))
you can add weights to your list, so that some are picked more frequently then others.
Right now I have:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(channel):
    time.sleep(2)

    channel = bot.get_channel(723954693826674701)
    brankos_greetings = [
        "testMessageCommon1",
        "testMessageCommon2",
        "testMessageCommon3",
        "testMessageCommon4",
        "testMessageCommon5",
        "testMessageCommon6",
        "testMessageCommon7",
        "testMessageCommon8",
        "testMessageCommon9",
        "testMessageCommon10",

        "testMessageSemiRare1",
        "testMessageSemiRare2",
        "testMessageSemiRare3",
        "testMessageSemiRare4",
        "testMessageSemiRare5",
        "testMessageSemiRare6",
        "testMessageSemiRare7",

        "testMessageRare1",
        "testMessageRare2"
    ]

    weights = [
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,
        0.077,

        0.03,
        0.03,
        0.03,
        0.03,
        0.03,
        0.03,
        0.03,
        
        0.01,
        0.01,
    ]

    response = random.choices(brankos_greetings, weights, k = 1)
    await channel.send(response)
```

However, this gives this output in chat: `['testMessageCommon1'] ['testMessageRare1']`. etc

I have tried:
`response = str(random.choices(brankos_greetings, weights, k = 1))`

and
`await channel.send(str(response))`

and
`response = random.choices(brankos_greetings, weights, k = 1).strip('[]')`

and
`await channel.send(response.strip(['']))`

But nothing works.

So my question is: How can I convert this list here to a string?

Comment: I forgot to add that

Comment: I tried that as well

Comment: A quick question: where are the `['who dis']` and `['hi']` coming from? Are these what you have in `brankos_greetings`?

Comment: Sorry, that's what the bot actually says but I changed it to something better to understand in the actual list.

Comment: It's about the [] and '' around the words

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My answer is posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choices()` returns a result as a list. Since you have `k=1`, this means that the returned result will be a list with one element. To send that element as a message, you need to index and access that element. In other words,

```
response = random.choices(brankos_greetings, weights, k = 1)
await channel.send(response[0]) # index the first (zeroth) element
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed it!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work
`response = " ".join(response)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the join() method to join the array of strings together.

```
response = ' '.join(random.choices(brankos_greetings, weights, k = 1))
```